I need to find an API for Deltek Open Plan
So really I'm looking for an API that links directly with Deltek Open Plan, has good, well written documentation and if that's not possible, any other solutions would be appreciated. I have found no real solutions, the closest thing being to use Deltek Acumen, another tool they offer to export data from Open Plan, but this is not quite what I am looking for. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.
